# I removed ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy and now there is no graphical interface

Tags: updates, graphics, 22.04, desktop-background, interface

I wanted to `remove` and `install` `ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy`, but when I remove it, the graphical interface went out instantly (now I know why!) And now I just have a black terminal. I installed `ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy` again but still no graphical interface. What should I do?
I have Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What was the exact command you used to remove what ever it was you removed. I can not find anything anywhere called ubuntu-wallpaper-jammy.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall all packages that come with default Ubuntu. You likely uninstalled the entire graphical interface in the process of trying to reinstall wallpaper, and in the future you should check what is getting uninstalled to be sure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: @David it's `ubuntu-wallpaper*s*-jammy`, which is the package that contains the wallpapers for Jammy

Comment: @Esther it was a typo. Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: @Esther Your solution worked. Thanks :))

Comment: @Esther Consider writing it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Esther I found out that by removing `ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy`, its dependencies were also removed. The following command reinstall all packages that come with default Ubuntu and fix the desktop issue.

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```